# Why does LLVMRunFunction with interpreter return same value for different functions?

Tags: llvm

I build 2 functions using the LLVM C API. Each returns a different pointer to global string ("first" and "second"). However when I run each with LLVMRunFunction using the LLVM interpreter, they both return a pointer to the string "first".

The problem does not occur when I return integers or function pointers.
I tried looking at the produced llvm code and it is correct, each function returns a different pointer.

Here's a sample that will reproduce the problem (on LLVM 7.0.1)

```
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    auto module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("test");
    LLVMExecutionEngineRef interpreter;
    LLVMCreateInterpreterForModule(&interpreter, module, nullptr);
    auto funType = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMPointerType(LLVMInt8Type(), 0), nullptr, 0, 0);
    auto fun = LLVMAddFunction(module, "fun1", funType);
    auto builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
    auto entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(fun, "entry");
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr(builder, "first", ""));
    auto generic = LLVMRunFunction(interpreter, fun, 0, nullptr);
    printf("%s\n", (const char*)LLVMGenericValueToPointer(generic));
    fun = LLVMAddFunction(module, "fun2", funType);
    entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(fun, "entry");
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr(builder, "second", ""));
    generic = LLVMRunFunction(interpreter, fun, 0, nullptr);
    printf("%s\n", (const char*)LLVMGenericValueToPointer(generic));
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output

```
first
second
```

Instead it outputs

```
first
first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a closer look at the generated LLVM, I noticed that the global strings built with LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr had the unnamed_addr modifier. When building the global string manually instead of using LLVMBuildGlobalStringPtr, the interpreter actually returns the correct string pointers and the output becomes as expected:

```
auto glbstr = LLVMAddGlobal(mBuilder.module_, llvmType, "glbstr");
LLVMSetInitializer(glbstr, LLVMConstString(toStringz(arg.value), cast(uint) arg.value.length, 0));
auto firstCharPtr = LLVMBuildGEP(builder, glbstr, [LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt8Type(), 0, 0), LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt8Type(), 0, 0)].ptr, 2, "");
```